# Как скрыть некоторые значения делений формата оси диаграммы excel

Tags: excel, диаграммы, формат

Я построила комбинированную диаграмму, и мне необходимо скрыть некоторые значения из двух вертикальных осей, а именно значения ниже нуля в левой вертикальной оси и значения выше 70-ти в правой вертикальной оси. Возможно ли это сделать?
Я конечно могу убрать значения ниже нуля в левой вертикальной оси, указав в параметрах оси минимальное значение =0, но мне бы хотелось, чтобы графики были расположены именно таким образом - один под другим:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наложить сверху непрозрачный объект с цветом фона

Comment: а, т.е. без шаманства никак. Я поняла ваш намек, но поступила иначе - построила две диаграммы и наложила нижнюю на верхнюю, минут 15, правда, ушло на подгонку вертикальных делений. Получилось неплохо (https://prnt.sc/5rquRO8k5xjg)